# Spark xgboost4j: How to get feature importance?

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I run xgboost on spark and meet `AttributeError: 'XGBoostClassifier' object has no attribute 'booster'`

```
def train_model(trainDF):
    xgboost = XGBoostClassifier(
        featuresCol="features",
        labelCol="label",
        predictionCol="prediction",
        objective='multi:softprob',
        numClass=10,
        missing=0.0
    )
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[xgboost])
    model = pipeline.fit(trainDF)
    featureScoreMap = xgb_model.booster.getFeatureScore()
```

How to get feature importance of xgboost4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-
Get the important features from pipelinemodel having xgboost model as a first stage

### In Scala

```scala
val xgboostModel = model.stages.apply(0).asInstanceOf[XGBoostClassificationModel]

xgboostModel.nativeBooster.getFeatureScore()
```

### In Python(from commentS)

```py
model.stages[0].nativeBooster.getScore("", "gain")
```

Comment: I'm using pyspark, another error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: `model.stages[0]` should work. fetch the xgboostmodel

Comment: What about this error `AttributeError: 'XGBoostClassificationModel' object has no attribute 'asInstanceOf'`

Comment: you should not use `asInstanceOf` - try below - `xgboostModel = model.stages[0]

xgboostModel.nativeBooster.getFeatureScore()`. Note i haven't these apis in pyspark

Comment: Yes, `model.stages[0].nativeBooster.getScore("", "gain")` is Ok.

Comment: can you please tell me how to print out variable names in feature importance results instead of f1,f2, etc.? I am having a hard time to print them out in scala

Comment: @EmmaStin, Are you using OHE before creating feature vector?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale no I don't.